# Парсинг из приложения на android

Tags: android

Всем привет. Хочу узнать, есть ли такая возможность: сделать скрипт, который будет на эмуляторе android запускать instagram, затем заходить на определенные профили и парсить инфу?

Почему не использовать обычные парсеры инсты? Потому что мне нужно спарсить email бизнес-аккаунта, что возможно только с помощью мобильного приложения.

Comment: Боюсь предеться распазновать текст, что довольно таки мутарно

Comment: @pavel1787mego да если даже не распознавать, то чтобы он просто скрин делал и на сервер его скидывал)

Comment: @pavel1787mego просто подходящую либу бы найти

Comment: Возможно, нужно смотреть в сторону [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html). Также для автоматизации есть библиотеки типа Selenium и Appium.